# Efficiently implementing modifying operations?

Tags: c++

I was wondering, suppose that I have some large object, say a matrix, and I want to provide some functionality to modify this object in some way (in the matrix case, we might wish to invert the matrix).

What would be the best way to implement the invert function?

Four options come to mind:

1. We could have a member function, Matrix::invert() that inverts itself.
2. The member function could construct a new, inverted matrix (something like `std::string::substr`)
3. invert could be a non member function that takes and modifies a reference: `void invert(matrix& m)`
4. invert could be a non member function that takes a matrix by value, inverts it, and then returns it: `matrix invert(matrix m)`

Right now, the fourth option seems the best to me, because if the user wishes to keep the original matrix, the original will not modified:
`auto m = matrix{};`
`auto m2 = invert(m);`

And if they only want the inverted matrix, they can do:
`auto m = matrix{};`
`auto m2 = invert(move(m));`
or
`auto m = invert(matrix{})` (this should be efficient because the newly constructed matrix will be moved into invert, modified, then rvo'd or moved out into m)

But this goes against the idea that operations that affect the representation of a class should be implemented as member functions. So ideally i'd like a way of implementing a member function `matrix& matrix::invert()` that modifies the parent matrix if it is being called on an rvalue, but leaves it intact and returns a new matrix if it is being called on an lvalue. Would this be the correct approach? And how could it be implemented?

Another option could be to implement a member that modifies the original, and a non-member that "does the right thing" depending on whether the parameter is an rvalue (in which case it will be moved) or is an lvalue (in which case a copy will be made). This still has two downsides:

1. more code, since now we have two invert functions
2. chaining is awkward, since we might want to say m.invert() but not want to modify the original matrix.

Example: https://gist.github.com/mfaizan/6631482

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It all depends of course, but it's often useful to have both mutating actions and actions that result in new objects.  Ex. your m.invert() method can modify the matrix in place.  It might more efficient than creating a new matrix (it can change existing values without having to allocate memory).  However it would be useful to have a way to create new objects disconnected from the orig.

You see this pattern on std::string:

```
string orig("abcd");
orig += "efgh";
```

This mutates the orig string and is likely able to avoid memory realloc.
However you can also create a fresh new string:

```
string newStr = orig + anotherStr;
```

Answer (score 1):

It is easy to imagine functions where destructive and non-destructive versions would be desirable. For example, A destructive reverse of a linked list can be more efficient because it does not need to make copies of container values. And no surprise, the STL has `reverse` (destructive) and `reverse_copy` (non-destructive), but `list` also has a `reverse` (destructive) member function.

It is also easy to imagine functions that can be implemented based on some restricted interface but whose efficiency could be vastly improved by knowledge of class internals. For example whether a matrix is sparse or not. I think in this case it is normal to have a generic interface that dispatches on argument type to helper functions.

Answer (score 1):

There's another possibility you might want to consider:

`bool invert (Matrix &);`

The matrix may be determined to be singular, in which case return `false` and leave the matrix unmodified. You need some way of reporting this case.

Whether you use Cramer's rule, etc., for small matrices, scale (partial) pivoting, or more efficient methods for large matrices, there are always precision limits. That is, the result will be affected by the conditioning of the matrix. The point being - even if a matrix is mathematically invertible - floating point operations may not yield an inverse.

The most *versatile* form for 'expressions' might be: `Matrix invert (const Matrix &);` - provided you have move constructor / assign operators. Perhaps with a `Matrix::Singular` exception class.